# Select all children from a range in browser?

Tags: javascript, dom, browser, selection

I'm trying to get an array of all the words I select with the cursor from the browser using the window.Selection() API. I can capture the selection itself with window.getSelection(), and then print those contents out via window.getSelection().toString(), but unfortunately that just joins the words together without spaces.

Instead, I'd like to select text and get an array of each of the words, because that's how they're actually being appended to the DOM (via PDF textlayer). So,

```
The brown dog jumps
```

returns

```
['The', 'brown', 'dog', 'jumps']
```

If you use .toString(), you simply get

```
Thebrowndogjumps
```

Now, if I use .getRangeAt() in order to get the range, that object will provide me with the anchor node (i.e., 'The') and the extentNode (i.e., 'jumps'), but I'm not sure how to capture what's in between. Accordingly, I can't select all of the text.

**NOTE: this is a pretty specific question involving the window.getSelection() API - PLEASE do not just assume this is some basic string manipulation nonsense and link to some 'possible duplicate' unless the answer you link to actually discusses the getSelection API.**

I am asking specifically how you get an array of words from the .getSelection() object that is returned.

edit: here's some code that I tried that fires onKeyUp():

```
  handleSelect = (text) => {
    const selectObj = window.getSelection();
    console.log(selectObj)
    let selection = selectObj.toString();
    console.log(selection)
    let ranges = []
    for(let i = 0; i < selectObj.rangeCount; i++) {
      ranges[i] = selectObj.getRangeAt(i);
     }
     console.log(ranges[0])
     let rangeObj = ranges[0]
     console.log(rangeObj.extractContents())
     debugger
    // let range = selectObj.getRangeAt()
    // console.log(range)
  }
```

[image]

It's a bit hacky, but I solved it:

```
  handleSelect = (text) => {
    const selectObj = window.getSelection();
    let selection = selectObj.toString();
    let ranges = []
    for(let i = 0; i < selectObj.rangeCount; i++) {
      ranges[i] = selectObj.getRangeAt(i);
     }
     let rangeObj = ranges[0]
    let content = rangeObj.extractContents()
    let str = ""
    for (let i = 1; i < content.children.length - 1; i++) {
      str += ' ' + content.children[i].innerText
    }
    console.log(str)
```

Basically the Range object has .extractContents() as a method which creates a documentFragment that is a list of HTMLElements, which you can then iterate through to create the selection string.

Comment: Please show us what you have tried. Your question doesnt make much sense without the code.

Comment: @yoursweater can you please replace the image for the equivalent code extraction so I could copy and try to play with it?

Comment: @RicardoRocha actually solved it... the key was finding out about Range.extractContents()

Comment: @yoursweater Nice! Post your answer and accept it so others could have your help if needed.

Comment: @RicardoRocha thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand clearly what you are asking, but maybe is something like this?

```js
let button = document.getElementById("button");
button.onclick = () => {
   let array = window.getSelection().toString().split(" ");
    console.log(array);
}
```

```html
This is a text! Nice to have a text selected!

<button id="button">Print selection</button>
```

But please, let me know I far I'm for the solution that you want so I could change the answer.

Comment: The problem with this is that because I'm grabbing the text from a PDF textlayer, each word is kept in a separate div with no spaces, so split(' ') doesn't work, as you're trying to split this text: "Thisisatext!Nicetohaveatextselected"

Comment: @yoursweater can you put an example of the content of the PDF textlayer that you are trying to extract information?

Comment: sure thing. Added that in for you.

Answer (score 0):

Got it! The trick is to use the method .extractContents that the Range object has in order to get an HTMLElementList containing each of the divs. From there, you can access their innerText values in order to append them into a string or array:

```
  handleSelect = (text) => {
    const selectObj = window.getSelection();
    let selection = selectObj.toString();
    let ranges = []
    for(let i = 0; i < selectObj.rangeCount; i++) {
      ranges[i] = selectObj.getRangeAt(i);
    }
    let rangeObj = ranges[0]
    let content = rangeObj.extractContents()
    let str = ""
    for (let i = 1; i < content.children.length - 1; i++) {
      str += ' ' + content.children[i].innerText
    }
    console.log(str)
```